# Who all can enable 'Marketing User' in Dev Org?

Tags: campaign, user-admin

I was trying to create campaigns and couldn't able to see them and then identified that in User details screen  'Marketing User' check box was not checked. After that I was able to create Campaigns.

I can see only 2 Admin profile is able to check this field while none of other user profile there is no option to enable it for DEV orgs.

Is there a way to enable them additional via Permission set or Is this feature limited for DEV ORG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Marketing user' feature comes under the [feature licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_feature_licenses_available.htm&language=en_US).

You can see in the **company information section** of your org that how many licenses are available for your organization.Generally for developer orgs 2 marketing user licenses are available.

[image]